# Compare multiple strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, compare

I would like to be able to compare multiple strings with each other and return `true` if they are all equal. If any of the strings equal "N/A" then they are to be ignored in the comparison. For example:

```
string1 = "hi";
string2 = "hi";
string3 = "hi";
string4 = "N/A";
```

would return `true`, but:

```
string1 = "hi";
string2 = "hey";
string3 = "hi";
string4 = "hi";
```

would return `false`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What code are you using to compare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you've stored the strings in a colllection like array or list, you can use [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
string first = strings.FirstOrDefault(s => s != "N/A");
bool allEqual = first == null ||  strings.All(s => s == "N/A" || s == first);
```

**Explanation**: you can compare all strings with one of your choice(i take the first), if one is different `allEqual` must be false. I need  to use `FirstOrDefault` since it's possible that all strings are "N/A" or the list is empty, then `First` would throw an exception.

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/7r5E9D)

Answer (score 6):

```
if (myStrings.Where(s => s != "N/A").Distinct().Count() > 1)
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use `Any()` instead of `Count()`.

Comment: Tried this but I can't get it to return `false` when one of the strings is different

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Normally i would agree, but how would you apply the same logic with an `Any`? `Distinct` returns unique strings so `Any` would always return `true`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: `.Skip(1).Any()`

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered but I figured I'll state the most obvious code to do this:

```
bool notEqual = false;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++) {
   for (int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j++) {
      if (!(list[i].Equals(list[j])) {
         notEqual = true;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

The idea is fairly simple.  With the first element, you have to look at the next (length - 1) elements.  However, with the second element, you've already compared it to the first, so you look at the next (length - 2) elements.  You end at length - 1 because at that point you'd compare the 2nd last and the last element, which is the final possible comparison.

By all means the above answers are far more concise/elegant.  This is just to show you what's actually happening on the most rudimentary level C#-wise.